# How can I make my JSF project find my css file?

Tags: java, jsf, path

I have a css file in this directory:

> D:\JavaProjects\MyGuessNumber\web\resources\css\bootstrap.css

And in my index.xhtml file I have:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
```

When I run this application as:

```
localhost:8080/MyGuessNumber
```

the css file loads just fine.

When I use:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyGuessNumber/faces/index.xhtml
```

the css is still there.

But when I do:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyGuessNumber/index.xhtml
```

the page loads, but no css? How I can I make this work?

**Edit: I am using: /faces/***

Comment: What's your `FacesServlet` URL mapping?

Comment: Sorry, it is :  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>

Comment: So you don't have `*.xhtml` as mapping?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I could not make it work. ( I am just learning. )

Comment: Add the `*.xhtml` mapping, clean and build your project and redeploy it.

Comment: Should I make it:  <url-pattern>/faces/*.xhtml</url-pattern>

Comment: There's a great example in [StackOverflow JSF wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). Try that. By the way, I already added a comment in a previous question explaining this.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still very confused on how these all work!

Comment: You should first understand how servlets work. This is well explained in [StackOverflow Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Once you understand how the Servlet and URL mapping works, then you will understand how to set up the URL mapping for `FacesServlet` (yes, this is in the end a Servlet).

Comment: This is very interesting: http://localhost:8080/MyGuessNumber/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap.css.xhtml?ln=css

Answer (score 1):

Without /faces/, this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyGuessNumber/index.xhtml
```

Will not be processed by:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Because you have specify in the web.xml file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

JSF2 does not generate the HTML from:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Even if you write code in your page index.xhtml, it will not be executed I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by adding below in your index.html,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```